# How to display username or hostname instead of host ip address in Jenkins output console?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, curl, command-prompt

I want to trigger a jenkins job remotely, so for that I am thinking to use curl commands.
I have written a python code that triggers a jenkins job remotely using curl command.
Command is

`curl -X POST https://my_username:my_password@my_jenkins_server.net/job/newsplus_pages_and_ewplus_items_api_tests/buildWithParameters?token=12345`

When I running this command in command prompt, the jenkins job is getting triggered, and I am getting 'Started by remote ip address {followed by ip address}'.

Can I change this ip address to hostname or username?

Please please help!!!